# R passing missing arguments through functions

Tags: r, rlang, nse

I can't seem to find an SO post that helps me solve this problem. My minimally reproducible example is:

```
bigfn <- function(x) {
  smallfn(x)
}

smallfn <- function(y) {
  y <- rlang::enquo(y)
  print(y)
  print(rlang::quo_is_missing(y))
}
```

The output of `bigfn()` is:

```
<quosure>
expr: ^x
env:  0x7fc93fc0f8c8
[1] FALSE
```

But I would like the quosure to be an empty quosure and `FALSE` to be `TRUE` to reflect the fact that `bigfn` propagated down a missing value through `smallfn`.

Additionally, I don't want to just move the `enquo` into `bigfn` because I would still like to be able to use `smallfn` independent of `bigfn`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps a pattern called "forwarding the dots" may be useful here. It preserves missing arguments and behaves well in the context of non-standard evaluation:

```
bigfn <- function(...) {
  smallfn(...)
}

bigfn()
# <quosure>
# expr: ^
# env:  empty
# [1] TRUE
```

However, if you do need to have specific arguments referenced by name, you will need to "tunnel" them with `{{` (which is shorthand for `!!enquo`) to `smallfn()`:

```
bigfn <- function(x) {
  smallfn({{x}})
}

bigfn()
# <quosure>
# expr: ^
# env:  empty
# [1] TRUE

bigfn(42)
# <quosure>
# expr: ^42
# env:  empty
# [1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not do:

```r
bigfn <- function(x) {
  if(missing(x)) smallfn()
  else smallfn(x)
}
```

Then, without changing `smallfn` you have:

```r
bigfn()
#> <quosure>
#> expr: ^
#> env:  empty
#> [1] TRUE

bigfn(2)
#> <quosure>
#> expr: ^x
#> env:  00000000119E8FD0
#> [1] FALSE
```